# how can I append some html code using js several times

Tags: javascript, html

Hy guys, I have the following problem...

I need to draw in some cases (ex. when edit, save, update, etc) a defined html **code** (is the one at the end of the post) using js but I don't want to explicitly add the whole code every time i need it, so I'm wondering... ¿Is there a better way than adding it to a var and then .append or .html the code? instead of building the code every time I want to make it into an object oriented approach with properties and building it when needed, is there a way?

This is **the code**

```
for (var i = 1; i <= lineas; i++) {
c += "<div class='row'><section>some html for example</section></div>";
c += "<div>some other stuff</div>";
}

$('#res').append(c);
```

By a better way to do this... I mean... or I'm looking for, some kind of object oriented way to doit, hope you guys get it.

Regards!

Comment: You can use a template (i.e. handlebars), but there is not a predefined better answer - as to do it multiple times still requires some kind of iterator and a function.

Comment: [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), and [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) or whatever the jQ versions are if you don't wanna go native. (EDIT: forgot cloneNode heh)

Comment: Perhaps reduce that mass of string concatenation to a smaller example to make it easier to help/understand what you're doing. Also, you use a variable called `data` in your example which you don't initialise anywhere, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mostly use the same formats, you can write an object that will define some commonly-used (in your judgement) helpers:

```
var helper = {
  sectionInDiv: function(divClass, sectionText) {
     var result = "<div class='" + divClass +"'><section>" + sectionText +"</section></div>";
     return result;
  },
  divOnly: function(text) {
     var result = "<div>" + text + "</div>";
     return result;
  },
  repeat: function (n, htmlText){
    var result = "";
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
       result += htmlText;
    }
    return result;
  }
...
}
```

and then use it:

```
var htmlToRepeat = 
   helper.sectionInDiv("row", "some example text") +
   helper.divOnly("some more text");
helper.repeat(10, htmlToRepeat);
```